# printf moves cursor to the beginning of the line

Tags: c++, g++, cl

I have the following snippet which I'm trying to log into the terminal for debug purposes:

```
void DebugVector(vector<string> word_list) {
  size_t word_count = word_list.size();
  for (int i = 0; i < word_count; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < word_count; j++) {
      if (i == 156 && j == 156) {
        fflush(stdout);
        printf("We're supposed to find the word with value lares; ");
        fflush(stdout);
        const char *wordi = word_list[i].c_str();
        const char *wordj = word_list[j].c_str();
        printf("Actual values are %s and %s", wordi, wordj);
        fflush(stdout);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using Windows with the *Windows Subsystem for Linux* feature turned on and when I'm building the program with the following command

`cl.exe /Zi /EHsc /nologo /Fe: C:\Users\user\Documents\VSCode_projects\test_program\main.exe C:\Users\user\Documents\VSCode_projects\test_program\main.cpp`

and after I run it, the output is

`We're supposed to find the word with value lares; Actual values are lares and lares`

However, when I'm running it from the bash terminal in Windows, after building it with the following command:

`$ g++ main.cpp -o main-linux.exe && ./main-linux.exe`

The output is

`and laresosed to find the word with value lares; Actual values are lares`

It looks like the cursor is moved to the beginning of the line right after printing the first string. From what I understand c_str only outputs null terminated values, so I don't understand why this could happen.

I've tried creating a concatenated `string`, using `cout` instead, and I'm getting pretty much the same result. Also, the word_list has about 10,000 words in it, so I believe I'm not accessing any out of range values.

Is there anything that I can do here to make the program output the correct value?

Comment: What is the actual contents of the string `word_list[i]` and `word_list[j]`? Do any of them contain a carriage-return character `'\r'`? Remember that in POSIX systems (like Linux or macOS) a newline is really only a newline, but on Windows it's a carriage-return/newline pair.

Comment: Also, why are you using old C-style `printf` for your output if you're programming in C++?

Comment: If I use `cout << "We're supposed to find the word with value lares; Actual values are " << word_list[i] << " and " << word_list[j]; cout.flush();` the program prints the exact same thing. If I don't include `cout.flush()` I get no output

Comment: Running `fflush(stdout); printf("wordi: %i, %i, %i, %i, %i, %i wordj: %i, %i, %i, %i, %i, %i", wordi[0], wordi[1], wordi[2], wordi[3], wordi[4], wordi[5], wordj[0], wordj[1], wordj[2], wordj[3], wordj[4], wordj[5]); fflush(stdout);` outputs the following: `wordi: 108, 97, 114, 101, 115, 13 wordj: 108, 97, 114, 101, 115, 13` The word appears to end in 13 which is not null terminated, but this might be due to some buffering issues.

Comment: I think I got it though. `getline` might read \n while in windows it reads \r\n which explains the carriage return.

Comment: I've actually written that output line before, but I was searching for possible reasons for why `c_str()` might not output a null terminated string. I think I found some possible reasons, so I decided to ignore it instead of thinking the last character is actually `\r`

Answer (score 3):

The issue was from the difference `getline()` makes when compiled with g++ and cl.exe. The vector was generated via this code:

```
if (list_file.is_open()) {
    while (getline(list_file, line)) {
      word_list.push_back(line);
    }
  }
```

`getline()` deals with new line in windows differently which is not very surprising. g++ will read the word including the carriage return (\r) value while cl.exe won't. This results in the print issue.

Answer (score -1):

you can access vector elements with subscripts like array
because its object and it has address storage values

YOU CAN ALSO use .at() method of vector
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/vector-in-cpp-stl/
here in the element access method

and c_str() here works fine! no issue with that...

Comment: Not true. std::vector provides an [] operator that can be used in a similar way to .at(). The .at() method additionally checks that your access is within bounds.

Comment: I m sorry I haven't  seen as used popularly that so  in fact it's array method so btw you are right